# MySQL PreparedStatement NullPointerException

Tags: java, mysql, nullpointerexception

I keep getting a NullPointerException when trying to run my Java application. It seems the problem is with the `PreparedStatement` code.

Here is my code

```
    Connection mc = null;
    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public GUI() {
        mc = DB.getConnection();
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 795, 486);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Forecast Data");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                try {
                    String query = "Select * from db";
                    PreparedStatement pst = mc.prepareStatement (query);
                    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

and this is the stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at GUI$2.actionPerformed(GUI.java:63)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is my DB class

```
public class DB {

    public static void main (String[]args) {
            getConnection();
        }

        public static Connection getConnection(){
            String uRl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/weather";
            String user = "root";
            String password = "0888150";
            try {
                String driver ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
                Class.forName(driver);

                Connection mycon = DriverManager.getConnection(uRl,user,password);
                Statement st = mycon.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM db");
                while(rs.next()){
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("City")+", "+rs.getString("date")+ ", "+rs.getString("Low")+ ", "+
                rs.getString("High")+", " +rs.getString("status"));
                }

            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }
        }
```

Comment: What line is 63? And how is `mc` initialized?

Comment: Line 63 is the PreparedStatement pst = mc.prepareStatement (query);

Comment: Yup, seems like `mc` isn't initialized.

Comment: @Mureinik, NO, `mc` is initialized here. I have edited the question; see again.

Comment: Print it out then - you'll probably see something in the initialization failed. there's no other part of line 63 than can cause an NPE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like `DB.getConnection();` is returning `null`.

Can you please share the code of `getConnection`() method in class `DB` and print the value of `mc` using `System.out.println(mc)`?

Ok. You are always returning `null`, change your `DB.java` to below class.

```
public class DB {

public static void main (String[]args) {
        getConnection();
    }

    public static Connection getConnection(){
        String uRl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/weather";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "0888150";
        Connection mycon = null;
        try {
            String driver ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            Class.forName(driver);

            mycon = DriverManager.getConnection(uRl,user,password);
            Statement st = mycon.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM db");
            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getString("City")+", "+rs.getString("date")+ ", "+rs.getString("Low")+ ", "+
            rs.getString("High")+", " +rs.getString("status"));
            }

        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mycon;

    }
    }
```

Comment: I added my DB class and also the the system.out.println(mc) returns null

Comment: Also, please do remember to accept your answers (all of them) if they have given you satisfactory answers (by clicking on the tick mark on the left of the answers), it would be helpful to the community